# is it a good way to store data in list array

Tags: android, list, android-listview

I am learning android and currently i am working on an android app, whose one tab is reserved for storing medicines and their description like there will be a list of medicines and when user click any item , he will get the description.My question is that , is it a good practice to store the values of medicines and their description as a list of objects? Are their dis-advantages of using this method to store data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use that approach on most of my projects and i never found and issue with it. I  even made an app involving contacts, wich deals with a considerable amount of data (given de way contact API works) and it works smoothly so my answer would be yes.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on amount of data you have..If its large store it in db and populate as and when required.

Answer (score 1):

Using a SQlite database is a possible solution for storing the list of medicines.  Using a database will scale well over time as the number of medicines increase.  Below is a link to the android related sqlite database API's.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html